# How to wrap 1-2 or more of the same class using jQuery without wrapping it with a different class in between?

Tags: jquery, wrapper

To make I visually understandable, I want this:

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <input type="hidden" />
  <input type="hidden" />
  <div class="a">content</div>
  <input type="hidden" />
  <input type="hidden" />
  <input type="hidden" />
  <div class="a"></div>
  <input type="hidden" />
  <div class="a"></div>
  <input type="hidden" />
  <input type="hidden" />
  <div class="bee"></div>
  <input type="hidden" />
  <input type="hidden" />
  <div class="a"></div>
  <input type="hidden" />
  <input type="hidden" />
  <div class="cee"></div>
  <input type="hidden" />
  <input type="hidden" />
  <input type="hidden" />
  <div class="a"></div>
  <input type="hidden" />
  <input type="hidden" />
  <input type="hidden" />
  <input type="hidden" />
  <div class="a"></div>
</div>
```

To become this:

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="JQueryWrap">
    <input type="hidden" />
    <input type="hidden" />
    <div class="a">content</div>
    <input type="hidden" />
    <input type="hidden" />
    <input type="hidden" />
    <div class="a"></div>
    <input type="hidden" />
    <div class="a"></div>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" />
  <input type="hidden" />
  <div class="bee"></div>
  <div class="JQueryWrap">
    <input type="hidden" />
    <input type="hidden" />
    <div class="a"></div>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" />
  <input type="hidden" />
  <div class="cee"></div>
  <div class="JQueryWrap">
    <input type="hidden" />
    <input type="hidden" />
    <input type="hidden" />
    <div class="a"></div>
    <input type="hidden" />
    <input type="hidden" />
    <input type="hidden" />
    <input type="hidden" />
    <div class="a"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The HTML inside the wrap is auto generated so I have to walk the path of jQuery.

There is always a 1 or more hidden type input above every siblings in the `.wrap` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find all the `.a` elements whose previous sibling is not a `.a` element(ie the start of each block) then find all its contiues `.a` siblings and call wrapAll() like

```
$('.wrap .a').not('.a + .a').each(function () {
    $(this).nextUntil(':not(.a)').addBack().wrapAll('<div class="JQueryWrap"/>')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rq0y16wt/)

Comment: I forgot to mention, there is always a 1 or more hidden type input above every siblings in the ".wrap" class

Comment: @Milo http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rq0y16wt/2/ - there is a minor problem... the hidden input's after the last `.a` element the group also is wrapped

Comment: hmm I am trying to edit around your code because the first .a's hidden input above it is not included in the "JQueryWrap" class. I need it as exactly as the mark up i edited. It is important to group them as it is.